# application's name attribute - What is it for?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Inside my android manifest file I have an application tag and inside is name property/label.For what is this used for ?

Comment: Would you mind reading some official docs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the `android:name` XML attribute, then, quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm), it is:

> The fully qualified name of an `Application` subclass implemented for the application. When the application process is started, this class is instantiated before any of the application's components.
>
> The subclass is optional; most applications won't need one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base `Application` class.

Comment: so this is the 1 name of the class that extends Application or 2 class that extends Activity

Comment: @Seba: This is the name of the class that extends Application. Quoting the documentation that I quoted above, it is: "The fully qualified name of an Application subclass implemented for the application"

Answer (score 0):

1. Application class in the Android is used for global settings or running entrance.
2. In the Android reference it describes the Application class: "Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created." [more](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android)